# How to auto rotate first view only portrait and second view only landscape mode ios6

Tags: ios, uiview, screen-orientation

How to auto rotate first view only portrait and second view only landscape mode ios6

I tried like this in first view

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

in Second/Detail view

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly is this within a UINavigationController.

If so you should subclass `UINavigationController` and add the following to your subclass:

```
#pragma mark - Auto Rotation
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
```

Then in each VC you can override the methods for which require and which do not require autorotation.